# Itextsharp 5.5 splitLate is extending the lastrow

Tags: c#, itext

I am constructing a large table in iTextsharp

I have one parent table when I am adding all child table as a row.
As I dont have control on the data that is getting filled in the table.
I am using 
table.splitLate=false.

Also I am setting this property to all the child tables

The last row of a page is getting extended if the next one does not fit there.

I have set this property

Table.setExtendedLastRow = false

But this does not help

If I use the default splitLate and splitRows ,and KeepTogether =false,the table is getting broken but lot of whitespace is coming, due to big rows.
Can you guys please help

```
    public void GetBodyPTables()
        {
           yield return AggregateStudentsInformation();
        }

        public void AggregateStudentsInformation()
        {
           var stuTable = PdfPTableHelper.Create(1);
           stuTable.KeepTogether = false;
           stuTable.splitLate = false;
           stuTable.SpacingBefore = 15f;
           GetStudentsPostGradInformation(ref stuTable);
           GetStudentsGradInformation(ref stuTable);
           GetStudentsPlus2Information(ref stuTable);
           GetStudentsSecondaryInformation(ref stuTable);
        }

        private void GetStudentsPostGradInforamtion(ref stuTable)
        {
           var postGradTable = PdfPTableHelper.Create(1);
           postGradTable.KeepTogether = false;
           postGradTable.SplitLate = false;
           //Getting info from Xml Schema
           var postGradInfos = XElement.Elements.value("StudentPostGradInfo");
           var headerCell = CellHelper.CreatePdfPCell("Student Graduation Information",this.ReportFonts.SectionFont,Element.ALIGN_CENTER,Element.ALIGN_TOP,1);    headerCell.PaddingBottom = 3f; 
           postGradTable.AddCell(headerCell);

           foreach(var gradElement in postGradInfo)
           {
              var postgradStudentInfo = gradElement.Element.value("PostGradStudentInfo");
              GetSingleStudentPostGradInformation(ref postGradTable,XElement postGradStudentInfo);           
           }
           stuTable.AddCell(gradTable); 
        }



private void GetSingleStudentPostGradInformation(ref postGradTable,XElement postGradStudentInfo)
  {
     var topTable = PdfPTableHelper.Create(18);
     topTable.KeepTogether = false;
     topTable.SplitLate = false;
     topTable.SpacingBefore = 15f;

     //18 column table is divided into 2 cells ,one 4 column cell and another 14 column cell
     topTable.AddCell(CellHelper.CreatePdfPCell("Student Id:" ),postGradStudentInfo.Element("StudentId").Value,_defaultBoldFont,_defaultPlainFont,CellHelper.CellBorder.None,Element.ALIGN_LEFT,Element.ALIGN_TOP,4);

topTable.AddCell(CellHelper.CreatePdfPCell("Student Name:" ),postGradStudentInfo.Element("StudentName").Value,_defaultBoldFont,_defaultPlainFont,CellHelper.CellBorder.None,Element.ALIGN_LEFT,Element.ALIGN_TOP,14);

topTable.AddCell(CellHelper.CreatePdfPCell("CGPA:" ),postGradStudentInfo.Element("cgpa").Value,_defaultBoldFont,_defaultPlainFont,CellHelper.CellBorder.None,Element.ALIGN_LEFT,Element.ALIGN_TOP,4);

topTable.AddCell(CellHelper.CreatePdfPCell("Instructor Comments:" ),postGradStudentInfo.Element("StudentId").Value,_defaultBoldFont,_defaultPlainFont,CellHelper.CellBorder.None,Element.ALIGN_LEFT,Element.ALIGN_TOP,14);
     postGradTable.AddCell(topTable);
}

           //Similar Implementation
           GetStudentsGradInformation(ref stuTable);
           GetStudentsPlus2Information(ref stuTable);
           GetStudentsSecondaryInformation(ref stuTable);
```

I have used table.SplitLate = false in every table. And by default table.SplitRows = true.

The report generated is of more pages. So for some section headers the last row is getting extended to the bottom margin if the next row does not fit there.

How to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Hi Folks is there anybody from c# or ITextsharp who can help me on this

Comment: I assume those people from iText who deal with table intricacies now for many months have been doing so for the iText 7 tables only and so don't have the iText 5 details in the front of their minds. Then you present a piece of code which definitely is not runnable as is but at the same time very long. If you presented a [sscce](http://sscce.org/), people might be more tempted to run your code and try and remember what to do.

Comment: iText 5 is officially End Of Life (expect an update of the iText website soon) and iText Software employees will only be answering iText 5 questions of customers who currently have a support contract. And as always: Stack Overflow is community support, answers are not guaranteed.